# How is the initial request made to the Access Server in Kerberos?

Tags: key-generation, asymmetric, kerberos

I'm trying to understand how Kerberos works, in particular how the initial client sends a request to the Access Server. Some [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_44CHD3Vx-0) videos I've seen say the initial request is partially encrypted using the client's password. First, what is meant by "partially" encrypted? Second, considering a password is just an arbitrary string I didn't think it could be used as a symmetric key. Can any string be a symmetric key? I thought it's a special process to derive keys.

In [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qW361k3-BtU) I heard the message is not encrypted but a nonce is used to prevent a replay attack. If this is the case, how exactly does a nonce prevent a replay attack? The initial request must contain the password/hash, otherwise where's the actual security from any machine requesting a ticket?

Comment: This must answer your questions https://www.tarlogic.com/en/blog/how-kerberos-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's the Authentication Service, not access service.

Why wouldn't a password be capable of being a symmetric key? It just needs to be the right length. Since Kerberos doesn't require users passwords to be a certain length what actually happens is the password is passed through a key derivation function (KDF). This output is considered the user long term credential. Both the client and AS need to know this long term credential.

What happens is the client sends the AS-REQ and the AS responds saying the user needs to do pre-auth. The client will resend the original request, but then the client will encrypt the current time to the long term credential and stick it in the pa-data list. This is the partial encryption bit. Only the timestamp is encrypted where the rest of the message is cleartext.

Comment: "Why wouldn't a password be capable of being a symmetric key?" so anything can be a symmetric key?

Comment: Yes, as long as both parties agree to it. Whether something is a *good* symmetric key is something else entirely though.

Comment: This is only true for symmetric keys, right? Asymmetric keys must be created in a special way and can't be anything.

Comment: Right. Asymmetric keys exist as pairs and have a special relationship. Each key is generally based on random prime numbers, and the protection they provide is derived from computing a math problem that is very hard to reverse without knowledge of the primes. Ideal symmetric keys are just perfectly random numbers.

Comment: Any idea what is meant by the request being *partially* encrypted? Like how can something be partially encrypted. [This is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_44CHD3Vx-0&t=2m24s) where in the video it is stated.

Comment: I already explained that in the last two sentences.

Comment: If symmetric keys can be anything then why do algorithms exist for their generation? What is the point of AES if it's trivial to create a symmetric key?

Comment: AES relies on the randomness of the key to provide the hardness. The randomness of a user password is not perfect so you use a KDF to distribute what randomness is in the password evenly across all bytes as well as to make it harder to brute force the password.